# In welchen Dialekten wird die Endung -n weggelassen bzw. nicht ausgesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation, dialect, regional

Bekanntlich lässt man in vielen deutschen Dialekten unter anderem die Endung *-n* weg:*

> ... die junge' Bube' spiele' lasse'...

Wie heißt das Phänomen und gibt es eine entsprechende Linie oder Dialektraum?

Die [Karlsruher Linie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karlsruher_Linie), [das Alemannische](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannische_Dialekte) und [das Pfälzische](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pf%C3%A4lzische_Dialekte) haben eine Beziehung dazu, aber da finde ich keine Bezeichnung mit einer 1:1-Entsprechung.

*anscheinend unabhängig von der Wortart aber natürlich mit vielen Ausnahmen (*Mann*, *an*, *neun*, *Schwerin*, *Bonbon*, *Orang-Utan*...)

Comment: Unter den „Ausnahmen“ sehe ich keine; es fällt einfach nur das _n_ nach Schwa weg, nicht nach anderen Vokalen.

Comment: Es gibt Instanzen wo *-n* nach Konsonant wegfällt (*Horn* im höchstallemanischen, und nach anderen Vokalen in Wörtern wie *Wein* und *Mann* in die meisten schweizerdeutschen Mundarten).  Kann sein dass da früher auch Schwa stand.  Einige sagen auch *i'* und *vo'*.  Andererseits sagt man im Donauschwäbischen zumindest *han* und *gwen*, die anderswo *haa* und *gwää* und so heißen.  Betonung spielt vielleicht eine Rolle.  Ich kenne auch nicht alle Dialekte, ganz im Gegenteil. :-)  Wollte da also keine Aussage machen, ist einer anderen SE-Frage wert.

Comment: Und ich weiß nicht ob alle Sprecher Lehnwörter wie *Lincoln* oder *Schenschen* automatisch einschwaben.

Comment: Im Hessischen ist das auch oft so.

Comment: So weit ich weiß liegt eine Grenze ungefähr da.  (Südlich des Nordhessischen.)

Comment: @chirlu Eine andere Ausnahme wäre vielleicht _15_ (_Fuchsn_ statt _Fuchse_).

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer Auch *zehn* hat keine Schwa-*n*-Kombination (es ist /e:n/)

Answer (score 1):

Im [AADG des IDS](http://prowiki.ids-mannheim.de/bin/view/AADG/InhaltsVerzeichnis) 
sowie im [Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de) fehlt eine direkte Aussage zu dieser Frage.

Im AdA steht [eine Frage zur Mehrzahl von *Mädchen*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/r8-f5e-2/).  Die schriftliche Wiedergabe der Aussprache ist ziemlich genau, dadurch lassen sich einige Schlüsse ziehen.

[image]

Andere vielleicht erleuchtende Fragen: [*Tunnel*, *Zimmer*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f20a-c/), [*Pedal(e)*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/pedale-plural/), [*Hähnchen*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/9_01b/), [*da drin*](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-3/f07a-f07h/).

Im Falle *Tunnel* wie in anderen Fragen finde ich aber dass die Forscher oder die Sprecher die Aussprache ohne *-n* manchmal normalisiert haben bzw nicht angeboten haben.  ([Hier](http://prowiki.ids-mannheim.de/bin/view/AADG/TenAuslaut) definitiv auch.)

Comment: Ich kann der Grafik nichts für die Frage Relevates entnehmen, kannst Du erklären, was Du aus ihr abliest?

Comment: Folgende Zonen sind *-n*-fähig: *Mädchen, Madeln, Mödzn, Diandl(a)n, Gitschn*...  Einige Varianten wie *Meedercher* kommen nur in Regionen vor wo sowieso keine große Frage ist.   So leben in folgenden Zonen wahrscheinlich *-n*-Verweigerer: *Mäd/Maad, Mäde, Mädel, Mädle, Mai*li, M*la, Meitschi.*  (*Mädels* sagt nichts aus.)

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6lsch_(Sprache) lässt *-n* auch weg.  Eine Insel?

Comment: Ich finde es fragwürdig, für die Beantwortung dieser Frage gerade den Plural eines Wortes heranzuziehen, das (a) ein Diminutiv ist (und somit anderen regionalen Varianten unterliegt) und (b) normalerweise bereits auf *n* endet (d.h. nicht-n-endige Wörter könnten im Plural durchaus kein *n* erhalten, obwohl die Karte die betreffende Region der Standardsprache zuordnet)

Comment: Stimm ich alles zu, es erleuchtet nur wo *-n* vorkommt, nicht wo es definitiv nicht vorkommt.  Daten die direkt auf die eigentliche Frage eingehen  - beispielsweise genaue Transkriptionen mehrerer Infinitive - hätte ich sehr gerne.